# Apache installation with mod_fcgi for httpd24 centos 6.9

Tags: centos6, apache2.4, mod-fastcgi, software-collections

I have installed php and apache in my centos 6.9 for apache version 2.4 and php version 5.6 as below:

```
yum install epel-release
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
yum install epel-release
yum repolist
yum --enablerepo=extras install centos-release-scl
yum install httpd24
yum install -y libapache2-mod-fastcgi rh-php56-fpm rh-php56 rh-php56-php rh-php56 rh-php56-cli
```

but I can't see mod_fcgi.so is in /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules directory.

Hence I downloaded the mod_fcgi from http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#mod_fcgid.

Need an way so that I can install it existing apache modules

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **httpd24** from Software Collection, you already have [mod_proxy_fcgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html), other old modules are deprecated.

I recommend you to read [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/) about such configuration (notice, this was written for CentOS 7 but works on CentOS 6 using httpd24)

Comment: one more issue, somehow I deleted /opt/rh/httpd24
and now onwards, when I install yum install httpd24, the /opt/rh is blank

and can not run sudo service httpd24-httpd graceful it says:

/etc/init.d/httpd24-httpd: line 50: /opt/rh/httpd24/service-environment: No such file or directory
/etc/init.d/httpd24-httpd: line 127: /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/apachectl: No such file or directory
[root@01HW559104 yum.repos.d]# service httpd24-httpd start
/etc/init.d/httpd24-httpd: line 50: /opt/rh/httpd24/service-environment: No such file or directory

Comment: reinstall the needed packages (yum remove httpd24-runtime; yum install httpd24)